# undefined var can't be detected in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have read two full threads on this topic and tried all available syntaxes liste from both of them, and the variable is still undetected.

```
var undefined = false;
if ( numLikes == undefined)
```

It's on this website: http://www.solidzapps.com/

If you use this script on the page, you will be able to find undefined likes, on many results:

```
$("#pageResults li").each(function (){

    var viewsText = $(this).find(".duration-viewCount").text();
    var numViews = +viewsText.match(/\|\s([^ ]+)/)[1].replace(/,/g, "");

    var likesText = $(this).find(".likes").text();
    var numLikes = +likesText.match("^([^ ]+)")[1].replace(/,/g, "");

    //i think numlikes * 80 > numViews is what you're looking for, change that if not
    if (numLikes < 18 || numLikes * (25 + Math.min(15,numLikes/5)) + Math.min(30,numLikes/18) < numViews)
    {   
        $(this).css("height", "0"); 
    }
    var undefined = false;
    if ( numLikes == undefined)
    {   
        $(this).css("height", "0"); 
    }


});
```

Comment: undefined != identifier

Comment: `var undefined = false; if ( numLikes == undefined)` makes no sense... What are you trying to accomplish with this part of the script?

Comment: Andreas, That makes no sense because it's unofficial, it's an alledgedly working coding trick. i took it from an answer that had about 20 up votes, from a page nearly the same as my question. It's a trick i found from the 2nd/3rd most popular answer for dealing with undefined vars, it had at least 20 votes.

Comment: Siam, I thought that your code worked at first, however, it selects every instance of the identifier, whether it is an integer or an undefined value, so in effect it doesnt work at all.

Comment: `numLikes` will never be `undefined` nor `false`. Also you cannot overwrite [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Comment: @Andreas, undefined is not a reserved word, so you can do something as silly as `(()=>{let undefined = 'hello'; console.log(undefined)})();` which will log `'hello'`. But this does actually matter only when checking `undefined ==[=] something`, everything that should be undefined will still be `window.undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have provided, numLikes comes out to be `'NaN'` attributed to this line in your code `var numLikes = +likesText.match("^([^ ]+)")[1].replace(/,/g, "");`

Try this:

```
if(isNaN(numLikes)) {
//do Something
}
```

or

```
if(!numLikes) {
// do Something
}
```

My previous answer didn't work because `typeof NaN` is `number` not `undefined`

Comment: `numLikes` will never be `undefined`

Comment: it doesnt work for this question, I had tried that already because i read 20 answers for coping with undefined values in other pages. nothing works for undefined on the solidzapps website for number of likes.

Comment: I can't get the case where 'numLikes' is undefined. Even when no search is performed there are no DOM nodes with selector as "#pageResults li".

Comment: Hey thanks, I added an example to the top of the page. I just typed acid jazz downtempo, set it to 50 results, and have two undefined results.

Comment: I want to say Thanks a lot! it's awesome, the isNaN version is working thank you.